# Xamarin iOS Button Click when keyboard open

Tags: ios, xaml, xamarin

I have a basic Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid with a text field and a button in it.

XAML:

```
 <Grid Margin="16"
      CornerRadius="12"
      Background="{StaticResource Color08Brush}">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
             PlaceholderText="Write a message…"
             Margin="12,12,4,12"
             MaxHeight="92"
             TextWrapping="Wrap"
             Text="{Binding [Input], Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
             Style="{StaticResource ChatTextBoxStyle}" />
    <Button Grid.Column="1"
            Command="{Binding [SendMessage]}"
            Style="{StaticResource EllipseButtonStyle}"
            Background="{StaticResource Color11Brush}"
            Width="44"
            Height="44"
            Margin="0,0,12,0"
            IsTabStop="False">
        <u:PathControl Style="{StaticResource ForwardArrowPathStyle}"
                       Width="8" />
    </Button>
 </Grid>
```

Everything works in Android. Having issues in iOS. When in the TextBox, the iOS keyboard opens as expected. You type some text and hit the Button to send the message. However, this merely dismisses the iOS keyboard and doesn't fire `SendMessage`

Tried using `ios:VisualElement.CanBecomeFirstResponder="True"` but same result on button click with keyboard open in iOS.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you please show the code in your `ViewModel` or backend? How do you use the binding command with the button? On my side, when changing the command to `Command="{Binding SendMessage}"`, it can work as expected, you can give it a try.You can refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#the-icommand-interface on how to use the binding command.

Comment: Hi Alexandar, it's not an issue with the command. It works in Android and UWA. It also works if I wrap the entire XAML in a `ScrollViewer` but this defeats the purpose of my Grid layout

Comment: Thanks for the update. This looks like a potential issue in Xamarin iOS on Github: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6409 , when the button is tapped the keyboard disappears but the button command does not trigger. You can follow up there.

Comment: Hello, I've tried the `ios:VisualElement.CanBecomeFirstResponder="True"` but same result. I believe this is because the XAML is constructed using `Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls`. Unfortunately, these controls need to be used as this is all part of a massive code base

Comment: Sorry to hear it doesn't work, since it's a potential issue, you can folllow up there: https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/6409